# Python scipy.optimize fitting by x-deviation

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, chi-squared, model-fitting

I have a simple fitting problem in Python - I have some data and a fit function, and all I want is to find the optimal parameters.

Thing is, my x data is my dependent variable, and my y data is my independent variable. So I want Python to find the parameters to minimise chi-squared with respect to the x-deviation, not the y-deviation as is the default.

The obvious solution would be to invert my fitting function and swap around my x and y parameters, but this is not possible due to the nature of the function:

y = a / (exp((v-x)/c) + 1) + d (i.e. a Fermi-Dirac step) which cannot be inverted without singularities/being undefined.

If anyone could help me reverse the nature of the chi-squared evaluation, that would be amazing! (Preferably not just writing a new optimization routine from scratch...)

S

Comment: The only possible solution that I can think of without inverting, is too use a Taylor series expansion, adding an error u term to the exp, and solving for du. I never tried that.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the error between y_i and a / (exp((v-x_i)/c) + 1) + d

for some parameters a,v,c,d and known data points {y_i, x_i}?

If so can you not just use curve_fit or leastsq here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html

Comment: I've now realised that the singularities in the inverse function cannot be avoided. I ended up using scipy.optimize, with a couple of extra fitting parameters thrown in to tighten the fit.